# How can I read a comment on a deleted post?

Tags: support

Someone directed a comment on a post at me and then the post was deleted.

Now I have a tantalising two-line snippet of the comment but, when I click to read the whole comment, it just takes me to a "Page not found" message.

Is there another way to access the comment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well not directly. You could get yourself up to 10,000 reputation which will allow you to view deleted posts ([among other things](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)).

However, if that comment itself was deleted then no, you wouldn't have the ability to view that comment. Moderators have the ability to view deleted comments, but that's not something included in the 10k tools.

Comment: Thanks JonW, in that case, would it not be better if the comment was removed from the notification system when the post was removed?

Comment: @AndrewMartin Yes, that would make more sense. Indeed, that should be current behaviour, but I'm sure there are some quirks out there. See the main MSE site which has [similar questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231668/how-do-notifications-on-deleted-posts-work)